# Rails server unexpected ':'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I work on a project, after the installation of Ruby on Rails (ruby 2.0.0 and rails 4.0.0), i take the source of my project and when i try to start my rails server i have this error:

```
C:\Users\alex\Desktop\Appli>rails server
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76: in `require': C:/Users/alex/Desktop/Appli/config/application.rb:38: syntax error    , unexpected ':', expecting end-of-input (SyntaxError)
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Application.rb:

```
        require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

    require 'rails/all'

    # Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
    # you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
    Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

    module Project
   class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de
  end
end

    # Set up gems listed in the Gemfile.
    ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)

    require 'bundler/setup' if File.exists?(ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'])
    # MySQL.  Versions 4.1 and 5.0 are recommended.
    #
    # Install the MYSQL driver
    #   gem install mysql2
    #
    # Ensure the MySQL gem is defined in your Gemfile
    #   gem 'mysql2'
    #
    # And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
    #   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html
    development:                                                  << line 38
        adapter: mysql2
        encoding: utf8
        database: project_development
        pool: 5
        username: root
        password: root
        socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Someone have already see this error?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you consider including  line 38 of C:/Users/alex/Desktop/Appli/config/application.rb? The only help we can offer if you're not going to show us any code is that you have an unexpected `:` on like 38.

Comment: Or even better, take a look yourself at line 38 of your `application.rb` and see if there's any stray colons or other invalid syntax.

Comment: why not share your `application.rb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, this is database config and should reside in `database.yml` and not in application.rb

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: project_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: root
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Secondly, avoid giving 4 tab spaces, give only 2, thats the convention. In the above database config I have followed 2 tab spaces convention.

Comment: Agree, the problem is that for some reason you've copied a chunk of database.yml inside application.rb.  The tab size isn't so much of an issue :)

Comment: Yes, just for the convention sake.